# Custom Function Using Column As Parameter

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, cyclic

I have a custom function created in the Power Query Editor that accepts two parameters.  One parameter should be dynamic based upon the value in a column.  When tested with static parameters, the function works correctly as far as using a static parameters goes.  However, if the table column is supplied (to provide the dynamic value needed), it produces a cyclical error. The function is invoked using "Invoke Custom Function".  The first parameter selects a field, while the second parameter is set statically.

The Invoke Custom Function that produces a correct result:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Rounded Up", "qryProjectedDate", each qryProjectedDate(5, -1))
```

The Invoke Custom Function that produces an error:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Rounded Up", "qryProjectedDate", each qryProjectedDate([RemainingBudgetDays_RndUp], -1))
```

The qryProjectedDate:

```
(TotalLoops as number, Loop as number) => 
let
CurrentLoop = Loop + 1,
output = 
if Calendar[IsWorkDay]{CurrentLoop} = 1
then  
        (if  CurrentLoop = TotalLoops - 1
        then Calendar[Date]{CurrentLoop}
        else @qryProjectedDate(TotalLoops, CurrentLoop))
else @qryProjectedDate(TotalLoops + 1, CurrentLoop)
in  output as date
```

This function produces a stack overflow error and a cyclical error messages.

Further testing of just inputting the column value as a parameter and returning that same value produces the value that I would expect.  Therefore, I believe my issue is in how I have written the power query M function.

Answer (score 0):

if **function(5,-1)** works then using **function([column1],-1)** will also work if column1 contains a numeric five

Are you sure the column is named **RemainingBudgetDays_RndUp** ? Spelling and capitalization of the column name matter. Try temporarily renaming that column and look at the output to see what powerquery thinks that column is named

[image]

Once that is set, is the column formatted as numeric or alpha? If not numeric, change the column type or use Number.From() in your function

[image]

Try calling your function using a table with a single row, and the contents of the **RemainingBudgetDays_RndUp** column equal to a numeric five. Does it work? Then the data needs cleaning on some of the rows

Are there any nulls, alpha characters, out of bound, or other data in the RemainingBudgetDays_RndUp column that will break your function? To guard against that, try adding a **try** and **otherwise null** before and after strategic points in the function

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and help!

Comment: You redirected my focus to looking at the data.  My data had negative numbers along with zeroes and positive numbers.  There was no nulls.  I am guessing that somewhere, since I am adding this number to a date to get a projected date, that it doesn't allow a negative number which makes sense.  Thanks again for the help!